# How to find out distict value from table and then count of every distict value with respective column in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, distinct-values, unique-values

**data_table**

```
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4 
car     train   plane   book    
bike    pen     car     Null    
tempo   train   car     laptop  
Null    train   tempo   book
```

**expected output**

```
distinct_value count_col_1 count_col_2 count_col_3 count_col_4    
car             1          0           2           0    
bike            1          0           0           0
tempo           1          0           1           0 
train           0          3           0           0  
plane           0          0           1           0
laptop          0          0           0           1
book            0          0           0           2
pen             0          1           0           0
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What *programming* question are you asking? You have to atleast try to come up with something yourself before we can say what is potentially wrong with it.

Comment: I can say what's wrong with it. This data structure is all wrong. I can't see any case when you're justified to use something like this, especially when you want to retrieve something like this result.

Comment: its simple mysql table with output.